# Batch/Powershell - Empty directory - mkdir with todays date - backup folders

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, batch, powershell

I'm trying to make a batch or a powershell script that:

First: Empties the folder C:\backup\

Second: Creates a new folder with todays date withinin c:\backup\

Third: Copies 2 folders c:\123 and c:\456 to the new folder created in c:\backup\

Anyone know how to make it work?

Also if possible hiding/starting the batch minimized and also 
hiding/minimized file explorer when it is copying the folders
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PowerShell Script should do what you need.

```
$dateFoldername = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$backupFoldername = "C:\backup\" + $dateFoldername` 
Remove-Item c:\backup\* -recurse -force
New-Item $backupFoldername -ItemType directory 
Copy-Item -Recurse "C:\123" $backupFoldername
Copy-Item -Recurse "C:\456" $backupFoldername
```

Obviously, you'll have to edit the paths to match whatever thing you are actually going to be using, but this should steer you in the right direction.

**Very Important:** As with any code you find on the Internet, you probably shouldn't test this on actual data first. I tested this on my machine with the above paths, however, your mileage may vary.

To launch the script minimized, make a shortcut or run the following from the command line:

```
Start PowerShell.exe 'C:\PathToScript\dated-backup.ps1' -WindowStyle Minimized
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Small thing, Would it be possible to display the date like this 2015-05-23 instead of 2015-5-23 ?

Comment: @Daniel I edited the script so that it should make the folder with the date you want. Please mark this as the answer if it is satisfactory to your needs.